# Sending Message to QueueChannel

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration

My knowledge of JMS is extremely weak so please bear with me.

I am trying to send a simple message to a Queue Message Channel.

```
@Autowired
private MessageChannel myChannel = null;

@Test
public void testRecieveMethod() {
    Message m = ((QueueChannel)myChannel).receive();
    System.out.println("HELLO");
}
```

The program hangs like its supposed to but **when I try and send a message from another program**, it doesn't seem to be getting recieved.

```
private MessageChannel channel = null;

@Test
public void testMessage() {
    channel = super.ctx.getBean("myChannel", MessageChannel.class);
    jackMessage message = new ameerMessage("Hello my name is jack");
    Message<ameerMessage> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build();
    channel.send(msg, 10000);
}
```

Here is my applicationContext

```
<int:channel id="myChannel">
     <int:queue capacity="10"/>
 </int:channel>

 <jms:inbound-channel-adapter id="JmsAdapter"
     connection-factory="connectionFactory"
     destination="myQueue"
     channel="myChannel">
     <int:poller fixed-rate = "1000"/>
 </jms:inbound-channel-adapter>

 <bean id="myQueue"
   class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
   <constructor-arg value="MYQUEUE"/>
 </bean> 

<bean name="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL">
      <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
  </property> 
</bean>

<bean id="myProcessor"
   class="com.jack.springintegration.Processor"/>
</beans>
```

Not sure where I why the message is not being recieved. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "another program". If it's really another program then they are different `myChannel`s.

I think what you want to do is send a message to JMS so the first program's `myChannel` will get the message from JMS.

You need to use an outbound channel adapter in the second program to send the message to the JMS queue.

Comment: I did have a look at an Integration book and it mentioned this somewhere. Thanks for clarifying this.